# Is my way for calculation of intermediate scattering function right?

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, scattering, molecular-dynamics

I have a C++ code for below formula:
$$F_{\text{s}} (\mathbf{k},t) = \frac{1}{N}  \langle \sum_{j=1}^{N}  exp\left( i \mathbf{k} \cdot \left[ \mathbf{r}_j (t) - \mathbf{r}_j (0) \right] \right) \rangle \nonumber $$
1- I calculate the difference between $x(t)$ and $x(0)$, and I do it for $y$ and $z$. (I don't calculate them with the below code)
2- the value of the $m = k . |\mathbf{r}_j (t) - \mathbf{r}_j (0)|$ is obtained.
3- the values of $p= sin(m )$ and $q=cos(m )$ are calculated, and then I sum $\sum p$ and $\sum q$
4- I calculate $z= { \sqrt{p^2+q^2}\over N}$
Do my way is right? because I cannot calculate right answer.

Comment: Why are you taking the complex magnitude $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$?

Comment: Dear @G.Smith I deleted the off-topic part. I just know whether my way is right

Comment: @G.Smith Is there not any || for exponential part? I mean, $F_{\text{s}} (\mathbf{k},t) = \frac{1}{N}  \langle \sum_{j=1}^{N} | exp\left( i \mathbf{k} \cdot \left[ \mathbf{r}_j (t) - \mathbf{r}_j (0) \right] | \right) \rangle \nonumber$

Comment: No, there isn’t. Or at least there isn’t in your formula.

Comment: The $F_s$ you initially wrote is complex. Are you trying to compute it or just its complex magnitude?

Comment: you are right, there isn't any || around $ exp\left( i \mathbf{k} \cdot \left[ \mathbf{r}_j (t) - \mathbf{r}_j (0) \right] \right) $ . but for calculation of $F_\text{s}$ I thought we should consider ||, because I dont Know how I should calculate it. Can we obtain $F_\text{s}$ and depict it versus time, while it has the imaginary part?

Comment: @G.Smith I just want $F_\text{s}$

Comment: To depict the evolution of a complex number, you can graph its real and imaginary parts separately, or its magnitude and phase angle separately.